# Is possible register two archive pages for single custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, archives, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I have a custom post type registered with `register_post_type( 'courses', $args );` ([like documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)), and I use template `archive-courses.php` for page `www.example.com/courses`. I'm using this archive to show default view, with some query string filters, with pagination, and default layout.

Now I need another page with **same** funcionalities of file `archive-courses.php` has, like paginations, query string and more.

I need use two URLs simultaneosly like `www.example.com/courses` and `www.example.com/calendar`. This second page need use same registered courses of post type `/courses`, but with different archive page. The idea is use differents filters for this page with different layout, but with all functionalities that are avaliable for `archives` templates.

The question:

1. Is possible register two archive template for same custom post type, but with different URLs?
2. If not (1), is possible publish one default page and trough some `add_filter`/`add_action`  load functionalities o archive template (like pagination, query strings)?
3. If not for all, has some suggestion to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at page templates?  Or set a specific page code (ie "page-courses.php")?

Comment: @rudtek the problem of use 'page-calendar.php' is that the 'page' doesn't have features of 'archive', this is the biggest problem at the moment =/

Comment: I'm not sure what "features" you're looking for as differences, but I've modeled a single page template to look like archives many times.

Comment: The "Features" is all functions is_... like is_archive, is_date, is_day, is_month. Also default pagination and all pages generated by archive like /category-calendar, /tag-calendar, and all that are available by default on "archive" pages.

Comment: Not sure if you're trying to be snarky or not, but to be clear you're asking for generic assistance on a site that is designed to assist with coding you've already created. You've provided no code nor details. Answering your 3 questions: 1. Not to archive pages.  2. It's possible to create the same functions and duplicate what a archive page will do on different urls. (using templates or shortcodes) 3. I've provided ideas, but without more specifics it's extremely difficult. Have you tried anything? Do you know wp_query? Being rude or short won't get you the help you need.

Comment: I'm not even sure if you're on a custom theme or someone else's.  Many themes you purchase have builders you can re-create archives.  Otherwise you'll need to build the functionality.  Did you look it a page template?  I'm SURE you can create a similar archive look...like I said I've done it.  Another option is creating your own query loop and designing bespoke.  We don't know your coding experience or level to know where to lead you.